# Make GWT application to work even in low bandwidth

Tags: java, gwt, bandwidth

I am working on a GWT application, where I want to use files for upload / download based on the internet bandwidth speed.
Is there any way to detect internet bandwidth / speed in GWT to decide which files to be loaded.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split your GWT application in parts, so that a part is loaded only when it is required. This is fully documented, see [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html). Very powerful stuff.
It makes the initial load smaller and faster, no matter what your connection speed is. Each time a new "feature" is used, a small additional package is downloaded (only the first time it is used). This works transparently if you follow the documentation.

Also, make sure you configure the web server properly, so that it makes full use of the cacheability of the GWT `*.cache.js` parts.

Answer (score 1):

Upload speed can change a few seconds after you have measured it, and then change again and again. And if you try to measure it before loading each file, the overhead of doing it may outweigh any benefits.

If this is critical to your app, you can offer a "full" and "simplified" versions of your app and let users choose. This is an approach used by Chess.com, for example, where connection speed is very important for player experience. Many websites offer a lighter "mobile" version of their apps compared to a more complete "desktop" version, which often means a different resolution for images as well.

Another approach is to allow users to choose between "standard" and "HD" resolutions for media files, but it can be applied to other file types too. This is an approach used by YouTube, iTunes (for movies) and many other websites.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't any thing providing this info, unless you try to download or upload something and measure the time in client side.

Measuring the download bandwidth could be as simple as compute the time you app got loaded, or better send a request to your server to ask for a known size request.

1.- Case 1 (I use [gquery](http://gquery.org) for simplicity)

Set this in your `index.html`

```
<script>
  window._app_start_loading = new Date().getTime();
</script>
```

Then compute the time your app took

```java
onModuleLoad() {
  double start = $(window).prop('_app_start_loading');
  double millisecs = start - Duration.currentTimeMillis();

}
```

And based on the size of your app JS and experience, you could compute whether the user is using a poor quality network.

2.- Case 2: But the example below has a problem, the user browser will cache requests, so it only works the first time the user runs your app. It is much more accurate and realiable to do something like:

```java
onModuleLoad() {
  final double start = Duration.currentTimeMillis();
  double millisecs = start - Duration.currentTimeMillis();
    GQuery.post("my_app/a_fixed_sized_request?" + Duration.currentTimeMillis(), null, new Function() {
        public void f() {
            double millisecs = start - Duration.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    });
}
```

Now you know the size is always the same, and the request is not being cached.

3.- Measuring upload. You can do the same that in case 2, but sending some POST data in the request with a known size. Replace the second parameter.